# Creating a calendar in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, calendar

I'm currently creating a calendar in HTML as part of a school project.

So far I've created the basics of the page. What I'd like is a calendar, where you're able to create appointments, which will then show up (like a basic calendar).

Here is what I've made so far (It's is danish, but I don't think it should be a problem. Let me know if you'd like it translated though):

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>December</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navigation">
                <div id="forrige">
                    <a href="november.html">Forrige måned</a> 
                </div>

                <div id="naeste">
                    <a href="januar.html">Næste måned</a>
                </div>
            </div>

    <br><br>

    <table class="ugedage">
                <tr>
                    <th>Mandag</th>
                    <th>Tirsdag</th>
                    <th>Onsdag</th>
                    <th>Torsdag</th>
                    <th>Fredag</th>
                    <th>Lørdag</th>
                    <th>Søndag</th>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="grayedout" data-href="#"><p>28</p></td>
                        <td class="grayedout" data-href="#"><p>29</p></td>
                        <td class="grayedout" data-href="#"><p>30</p></td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">1</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">2</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">3</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">4</td>   
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">5</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">6</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">7</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">8</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">9</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">10</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">11</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">12</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">13</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">14</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">15</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">16</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">17</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">18</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">19</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">20</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">21</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">22</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">23</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">24</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">25</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">26</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">27</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">28</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">29</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">30</td>
                        <td class="dato" data-href="#">31</td>
                        <td class="grayedout" data-href="#"><p>1</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="grayedout" data-href="#"><p>2</p></td>
                        <td class="grayedout" data-href="#"><p>3</p></td>
                        <td class="grayedout" data-href="#"><p>4</p></td>
                        <td class="grayedout" data-href="#"><p>5</p></td>
                        <td class="grayedout" data-href="#"><p>6</p></td>
                        <td class="grayedout" data-href="#"><p>7</p></td>
                        <td class="grayedout" data-href="#"><p>8</p></td>
                    </tr>

            </table>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.ugedage {
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
}

.ugedage th {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.ugedage td {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

.grayedout {
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    font-size: 12;
}

.dato {
    color: black;
    font-size: 12;
    text-decoration: none;
}

td a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.grayedout p {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 12;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#forrige {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1%;
}

#naeste {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

table td[data-href] {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

The small Javascript (I haven't learned Java yet, this was something I've found online):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('table td').click(function(){
            window.location = $(this).data('href');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

So far I've only created a calendar for the current month and the following 2, since I'm doing them manually (if you know how to automate this process I'd like to know as well, but it's not the most important thing). 
The thing I'd like is, when I click one of the `<td>` 's, that represent the days, a popup window, or something like that, appears, where I'm able to type in the details of the appointment I want to add.

How could/should I do this? From my understanding, it'd be difficult/impossible to do in HTML purely, which is where my problem is; I don't know anything else than basic HTML and PHP, and have never worked with Javascript, so I'm in a bit of a tough spot.

Let me know if you need any additional information, and I'll be glad to give you whatever I can.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Javascript and Java are different languages. Just saying.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia I didn't know that, I'll try to correct my post. Thanks :-)

Comment: this gonna be a hard one you probally should need some javascript/jquery

Comment: this was my problem before when i was still a beginner. what i did is just the same idea as what you're trying to do. on click of a day. pass the whole date to another page and then use them for saving or whatever.. that's it if you want to leave it with php and html

Comment: You can use some external open source project like this: https://fullcalendar.io/ easy to use and if you need help just make a new question and ask me (:

Comment: @Semi-Friends That could be my plan B, but I'm gonna try to make it work the other way first :)

Comment: @N.Smeding Thank you, I'll give it a look :P

Answer (score 0):

I've coded up the code you need in jQuery.

```
let row = $('tr');
row.each((index,row) =>{ // For each row

    if(index !== 0) return; // We only want 1 entry of!

    $('td').each((index,day) => { // For each day
        if($(day).hasClass('grayedout')) return; // Skip grayed out days

        $(day).on('click',addApointment); // The part we care about
    });
})

function addApointment() {
    let dayNum = $(this).text();
    let appointment =
    prompt(`What would you like to add for an appointment for the ${dayNum}th?`);
}
```

[JSFindle](https://jsfiddle.net/FrenchMajesty/tcg404s4/)

dayNum returns the day number that was clicked on and appointment returns what the user wish to add for his appointment. You can use that in your PHP, Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
// I’ve been using this component for my projects:

<html>
<script src="https://jsuites.net/v5/jsuites.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jsuites.net/v5/jsuites.css" type="text/css" />
<input id='calendar' />
<input type="button" value="getValue()" id="btn" />
<script>
let instance = jSuites.calendar(document.getElementById('calendar'), {
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM',
    time: true,
    onchange: function() {
        console.log(arguments)
    }
});

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(instance.getValue());
});
</script>
</html>

//Here's the link if you want to check it out:
https://jsuites.net/docs/color-picker
```